# Press 3th party claim and have them become a vassal?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I just came to the conclusion that simply pressing someone else claim does not make them a vassal of you but grands them independence, which has been "too" nice of me. So what could I have done to avoid this?

After doing some reading I came to the conclusion that if I had the guy I pressed the claim for already had as a vassal he would remain a vassal of me. So I just had to give him one of my titles? I have several other weak claims from people in my court but I want to make sure I do not lose the title I give to them once I press there claim.

Is this true and are there any other ways to have them become my vassal?

Comment: I believe that it is the only way, however it is noteworthy that pressing a claimants claim gains very high relationship bonus, this may allow you to revoke the original title without creating an enemy (however you will still suffer a tyranny modifier)

Comment: @nickson104 So I can get someone with a weak claim on the `Kingdom of England` to join me. If I grant him a title of me I can attack England and he will own it and become my vassal? I currently can win this easily, the current ruler has no allies he can call in to war and is very busy getting as kicked in the `Holy Roman Empire`. It would get me a step closer to unite Britannia.

Comment: Hmmm, I got him to my court and he does have a weak claim on `England` and on the `Holy Roman Empire`. But I am not getting the claim on `England`.

Comment: @MennoGouw A weak claim can only be pressed under limited circumstances. The current king of England must be a minor, infirm, female or already in a claim war before you can press it, and in either case the same handycap must not apply to your claimant.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/95188/68226) is pretty much a dupe – highly suggest reading. Pressing 3rd party claims is the most reliable means of rapid expansion for feudalism, until you're large enough or well connected enough to holy war an entire religion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to give your vassal a title before you win the war. A barony is enough.

An alternative option which is available when they are not married and have no kids yet is to marry them to someone who has (or will soon inherit) a title in your realm with the title-holder being the dominant part (a matrilinear marriage should be possible when she is landed and he is still a nobody). The claimant won't be your vassal, but their heir will be.

Keep in mind that neither method will work when the contested title is the same or higher rank than yours. Example: When you are a king and press a baron's claim on a kingdom, he will become an independent king because as a king you can not have other kings as vassals.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. So I basically need to claim a couple of Duchies and create the title for the kingdom myself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

1. Have them as a landed vassal already. If they are going to get a kingdom out of the claim, you will need them to be a king vassal already (even if you are an emperor), if they are only a duke or lower they will become independent (if 2 is not met)
2. Have them be a member of your dynasty. if you press a dynasty member's claim, they will automatically becomes your vassal (if lower rank).
3. Have their lands pass to your control. Ensure their heir will be your vassal. Generally you use this option instead of 1 only if the claimant is a female you can't land
4. Have their lands pass to someone you will control. This is different from 3 only in the fact that this is, as far as I know, the only way to press a claim of same rank to any use. For example, if you use the other 3 options for an empire, it will always end up outside of your control. Thus, you need to ensure the empire will be claimed by someone will pass it to a character you are current playing as. This generally means marrying a woman with a claim and pressing it so your shared heir will have both your lands. This is the only way to gain an entire empire at once I think.